# Why am i getting index error on this one hot encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('netflixprice.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:,0].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1:6].values

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))
```

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
      3 ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
----> 4 x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))
```

[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxwWg.png)

New to this. Also anywhere i can learn more about data processing ?

Comment: What is the shape of `x` and output of `x.head()`. Are you sure about `x = dataset.iloc[:,0]`? Do you have only one feature?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell anything without knowing the structure of your data. However, it seems like you may want to reshape your `x`:

```
x = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

I could find a dataset that might be similar to yours and tried it, it worked.

As for learning how to process the data: I personally try to refer to the documentation of a method I want to apply. In your case it's [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html). However, a clue to where the problem was I could find in the error message:

> ```
> def _get_column_indices(X, key):
>      """Get feature column indices for input data X and key.
>  
>      For accepted values of `key`, see the docstring of
>      :func:`_safe_indexing_column`.
>      """
> -->  n_columns = X.shape[1]  # this is where the problem is
>      key_dtype = _determine_key_type(key)
>      if isinstance(key, (list, tuple)) and not key:
>          # we get an empty list
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
> ```

That made me suspect that you got an ndarray shaped (n,) when sliced `x`, which doesn't have columns that were required.

It also seems like you intended `x` to be the target rather than the only feature. With 6 other columns assigned to `y` you may want to swap `x` and `y`. You may still encode your target like you planned.